# Cannot update data in html file while using service subscribe but ts console shows data

Tags: angular, service

I've used service file and subscribe to watch the public variable, I'm getting response in inner ts file but html not updating. HTML side rendering is not working but subscribe and receiving props working on all ts file

Here are the code

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'swap';
  constructor(private flowerswapService:FlowerswapService,public toastr: ToastrManager){
    this.flowerswapService.sendClickEvent();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

flowerswap.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { ToastrManager } from 'ng6-toastr-notifications';
declare let window: any;
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FlowerswapService {
public address = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
constructor(public toastr: ToastrManager
    ) { }
private subject = new Subject<any>();
getClickEvent(): Observable<any>{ 
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
ngOnInit() {
}
sendClickEvent()  : any;
sendClickEvent() {
    window.web3 = window.web3.currentProvider;
    window.web3 = new window.Web3(window.ethereum);
    window.ethereum.enable();        
    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', (function (accounts) {
    this.address.next(accounts[0]);
    }).bind(this));    
    window.ethereum.on('networkChanged', (function (netId) {
    console.log('network',netId)
    window.web3.eth.net.getNetworkType((err, netId) => {
        console.log("netId", netId);
    }); 
    }).bind(this));
    window.web3.eth.getAccounts(async (err, retAccount) => {
    if (retAccount.length > 0) {
        this.address.next(retAccount[0]);
    }else{
        this.address.next('');
    }
    if (err != null) {
        this.address.next('');
        console.log("err ---> ", err);
    }
    });
}
}
```

header.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FlowerswapService } from '../../flowerswap.service';
@Component({
selector: 'app-header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() address: any;
constructor(private flowerswapService:FlowerswapService) { }
ngOnInit() {
}
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.flowerswapService.address.subscribe((result) => {
    if(result != this.address){
        this.address = result;
        console.log('this',this)
    }
    });
}
}
```

header.html

```
<span>{{address | async }}</span> /  <span>{{address}}</span>
```

HTML side rendering is not working but subscribe and receiving props working on all ts file

Comment: You don't need `{{address | async }}` since address is not a observable

Comment: address is not observable and its @Input() property, and its not good practice to change Input property directly.

Comment: I've tried with or without async and with and without @input(). But still same results

Comment: Its not only updating inside web3 alone.. problem on that only.. please provide solution to work inside web3